Understand how the references returned by MemoryMarshal are working with GC
So here is a code:
    private ref TE ElementRef(uint Index)
    {
        ref TE Data = ref MemoryMarshal.GetArrayDataReference(this.Objects);
        return ref Unsafe.Add(ref Data, Index);
    }

And then I'm getting a reference to an element:
    ref TE ElementRef = ref this.ElementRef(Index);

Considering that the array "this.Objects" won't be modified by the app, my concerns are what the GC could do? Is it possible that "ElementRef" would become somehow invalide?

Still might not be safe: why would you want to do this and not just use spans or the array itself? Are you trying to avoid bounds checks, and if so why?

Yes, for an extreme optimisation.

Can you show what you're doing, the full picture. I'm curious if this is actually necessary or whether there is a better way.

That's an Object Pool similar to the ArrayPool, but which can Rent and Return objects of the same type.

GC will only dispose an object when there are no links to the object.  Otherwise, you could get an exception if you tried to access an object that was disposed.  ElementRef is a link to the object so until ElementRef is disposed your object will not get disposed.

AFAIK there is special handling for ref roots (which can only live on the stack anyway). Either way, they are tracked by GC, so will not be moved underneath you and are safe. Unless you do silly things like Unsafe.AsPointer.

@jdweng > "ElementRef is a link to the object" >>>
The ElementRef points to somewhere in the middle of the Objects array. I don't care about the object at the index in the array, but about the entire array itself. If the array is moved by the GC to a different address, the reference has to be updated or it gonna point to the place the array was before the movement.

GC does not move data.  I do not think GC does any defrag.  You can have multiple links to an object.  GC is done in background and when memory is needed.  It is designed not to have significant impact on performance.


Considering that the array "this.Objects" won't be modified by the app, my concerns are what the GC could do? Is it possible that "ElementRef" would become somehow invalide?

No it won't become eligible for garbage collection because the "ref" keyword is a strong reference to the object and there is no danger of getting invalid reference or NullReferenceException.
the only scenario I can think of an object might get collected by GC is when using some COM scenarios or some interop scenarios but this type of operations you're doing is GC friendly and won't get collected( of course you always should stay in the boundaries of an object to prevent exceptions/ crashes)

I wonder if the array could be moved for instance to pack the memory.

Yes it does. It is GC friendly and doesn't interrupt any of the GC algorithms and objects can be moved around by GC to higher generations if you want it.

Good question. While I'm uncertain about my response, C# uses the mark-and-compact algorithm. This means that even if your object has a long lifespan and wouldn't typically be collected, the compact phase will relocate the object to prevent fragmentation. Therefore, I believe your reference will change and become useless.
As far as I remember, the compiler doesn't permit storing references as fields, which is understandable. However, if you use references only within the local scope of your method and watch out for closures, you can avoid potential problems.

Yes, I use it only to avoid the bounds check, all reads/writes from/to the array  happens in a small method's scope.

"your reference will change and become useless" GC tracks ref pointers so it's perfectly safe. "you can avoid potential problems" the fact that they're local variables is not what makes this safe. If it was unsafe it would still be unsafe.
